# Mysql - Concat multiple INT fields together to make DATE field

Tags: mysql, date, date-formatting

I am working ona  small project for a client, and the data in the database is causing me a bit of bother. I am completing a search form for paid installments from the database. I can get the data fine, its the date fields which are giving me bother.

There are separate fields for the date, month and year for each installments. Is there a way I can use `CONCAT` or `DATE` or maybe even use `CAST` on the combined fields to search for the data.

I have tried the following

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT( received_date, received_month, received_year ) ,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) FROM policy_installments
```

AND

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('pit.received_date', '-', 'pit.received_month','-', 'pit.received_year'), '%d-%m-%Y') AS mydate, '%d-%m-%Y') AS modate FROM policy_installments pit ORDER BY mydate
```

AND

```
SELECT * FROM policy_installments WHERE CONCAT(CAST(received_date AS CHAR),"-",CAST(received_month AS CHAR),"-",CAST(received_year AS CHAR)) >= '1-1-2014' AND CONCAT(CAST(received_date AS CHAR),"-",CAST(received_month AS CHAR),"-",CAST(received_year AS CHAR)) <= '31-3-2014'
```

When I use the following I get some unexpected data:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS( received_date,  "-", received_month,  "-", received_year ) FROM policy_installments
```

RESULT

```
2d313130312d3132303039
2d3237313032372d323732303039 etc etc
```

Each of the 3 fields are type `INT(11)`.

However, none of these give me the correct data. Is there a way i can convert all 3 fields and use a date to pass into the query to enable me to correctly grab the correct data?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert a concatenated string to date, string should be in the same format as what you are using to convert.

For a date-string in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, should be converted to sql date using `%d/%m%Y` format.

**Example**:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE( 
         CONCAT( received_date, '/', received_month, '/', received_year ),
         '%d/%m/%Y' 
       ) as rcvd_date
FROM policy_installments
```

---

And to compare with other dates, you can use `BETWEEN` clause.

**Example**:

```
SELECT * FROM policy_installments 
WHERE 
    STR_TO_DATE( 
      CONCAT( received_date, '-', received_month, '-', received_year ),
      '%d-%m-%Y' 
    ) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE( '1-1-2014', '%d-%m-%Y' ) 
          AND STR_TO_DATE( '31-3-2014', '%d-%m-%Y' )
```

**Refer to**:
[**MySQL: STR_TO_DATE(str,format)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date): Convert a string to a date

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you want to avoid performing the function on the column. Instead, perform the function on the literal, so that you can utilize indexes on the columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM policy_installments 
WHERE received_year = YEAR('2014-03-31')
  AND received_month = MONTH('2014-03-31')
  AND received_date = DAY('2014-03-31')
```

Add a multi-column index on received_year, received_month, and received_date, you'll be doing pretty good.

Obviously, this method will only work for `=` comparisons. For `<=`, it becomes a bit more complicated:

```
SELECT *
FROM policy_installments 
WHERE 
  received_year < YEAR('2014-03-31')
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM policy_installments 
WHERE 
  received_year = YEAR('2014-03-31')
  AND received_month < MONTH('2014-03-31')
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM policy_installments 
WHERE 
  received_year = YEAR('2014-03-31')
  AND received_month = MONTH('2014-03-31')
  AND received_date <= DAY('2014-03-31')
```

But this longer query is still able to utilize the index.

To simplify things, consider creating an actual date column and keep it updated with the proper value.

Comment: The previous answer worked fine. However you mentioned using a date column, how could I update every field so the new date column would reflect the concatination of the 3 specific date fields? And would a trigger be a good idea for the table?